# Import Contribution failing, how to fix?

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, contacts, custom-fields, error

Receiving following error in drupal when importing contribution from a csv. Is there a quick fix for this?

> Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in
> CRM_Import_Parser->parsePseudoConstantField() (line 565 of
> /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bao in
> CRM_Import_Parser->parsePseudoConstantField() (line 563 of
> /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php).

These are the fields I am trying to import

- ContactID
- Total Amount
- Financial Types
- 1 Custom field (I have    imported this custom fields previously)
- Eligible for giftaid (giftaid    extension) (I have imported this
  previously)
- Received Date
- Contribution Source

Comment: It might help if you can post:
* The full error from the CiviCRM logs from the time of the error
* A sample of the file with the column headers (personal data removed if needed)

For the CiviCRM logs usually you can look on your server in site/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog
(replace with wherever the Drupal files folder for your site is stored if different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This patch fixed the problem. Thanks to @skherraz

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1269